# Highlighting an area of an image map based on search text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highlight, imagemap

This is a new question feeding from another question that was just answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498131/how-to-highlight-an-entire-div-based-on-search).

I am working to highlight a `<div>` based on search text. We've accomplished that, thanks to Alex.

Now, I'm trying to apply the same concept to mapped coordinates on an image map.

There's a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/y8GUc/3/).

**Here's the JS(jQuery 1.10.2)...**

```
function doSearch(text) {
    $('#content div').removeClass('highlight');
    $('#content div:contains(' + text + ')').addClass('highlight');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a method without SVG, you can use the [Maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) jQuery plugin ([GitHub](https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight)).

I have updated your **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grigur/y8GUc/5/)**.

```js
function doSearch(text) {
    $('#content div').removeClass('highlight');
    $('#content div:contains(' + text + ')').addClass('highlight');

    $('#Map area').mouseout(); 
    $('#Map area[data-text*="' + text + '"]').mouseover(); 
}
$(function() {
    $('#imgmap').maphilight({ stroke: false, fillColor: "ffff00", fillOpacity: 0.6 });
});
```

*Note:* For a better result just use a bigger image, because your *bunny.jpg* is too small and you have forced its size with height/width attributes.

Comment: Why is it repeating the image in the fiddle. You said I should use a bigger image... I adjusted the size of the image and set it to `width="100%"` and `height="auto"` and it repeated the image all over the page. Is this something that's contained in the external maphilight.js script?

Comment: I mean you have to use the image without width and height attributes or CSS. Just resize the image with an image editor before using it. This seems to be a limitation of Maphilight.

Comment: I have found the solution for Maphilight resizing problem **[here](https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight/issues/8)**. You have to change the Maphilight code, around line 156 the following should be added:
`backgroundSize: this.width +"px " + this.height + "px",`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with image-maps and area elements, because those are non visible elements, that cannot have child elements, nor styles. You would have to do it a lot more complicated like described [here](http://www.mediaevent.de/xhtml/area-map.html)

But **it is possible** using modern embeded SVGs - Almost every browser does support it nowadays. Even IE.

I tested it with Chromium and Firefox.

It cannot be done with the help of jQuery as far as I know but with usual Javascript. The key is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="663px" height="663px">
        <image xlink:href="http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/bunny.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="663" height="663" />
        <circle class="office" cx="504" cy="124" r="94" />
        <circle class="fire-exit" cx="168" cy="150" r="97" />
        <circle class="main-exit" cx="378" cy="589" r="48" />
</svg>
```

_

```
var svgns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var areas = document.getElementsByTagNameNS(svgns, 'circle');
$(areas).each(function(elem) {
    if(areas[elem].className.baseVal === text) {
        areas[elem].className.baseVal += ' highlightsvg';
    } else {
        areas[elem].className.baseVal = areas[elem].className.baseVal.replace(' highlightsvg', '');
    }

});
```

See [here in the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNm46/1/). Is that the way you want it?

Comment: Yes. That's a great start. I'm going to work on implementing this shortly. I'll be back. Welcome to SO!